# Reassembling a bitmap from its Pixel Information

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, bmp

```
void copyBitmaptoBuffer(HDC hdc, HBITMAP bitmap)
{
    BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = { 0 };
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);

    GetDIBits(hdc, bitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    char* lpPixels = new char[MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];

    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = abs(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight);

    GetDIBits(hdc, bitmap, 0, MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight,
        lpPixels, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    strcpy(picbuffer, lpPixels); //copy bytes to outputbuffer

}
```

I have a buffer of pixel data, but I am unable to find a way to reverse this process back into an image. For instance, I want to send this through a socket connection and assemble it back into a bmp file on the client. Preferably without an external library.

How do you build a bmp from raw buffer pixel data?

Comment: I suggest just sending the raw bytes of a `*.bmp` file instead, see the `BITMAPFILEHEADER` structure, that way consumers can use any library to usefuly load it directly from the network stream.

Comment: Also, do NOT use `strcpy` for copying raw bytes because it stops when it encounters the first zero byte value. It's also susceptible to buffer-overflows.

Comment: And you tagged this question with the `C++` tag but your code is not idiomatic C++ (e.g. using `std::copy` and smart-pointers). FWIW your code has a huge memory leak because you're not freeing the `lpPixels` buffer before you return.

Comment: You build a BMP file by writing a BMP file header, the BitmapInfoHeader, an the raw data. If you only want to send the picture through a socket then you can just skip the file header. The info header has sufficient information about the size of the following pixel data.

Comment: use `CreateDIBitmap` or `CreateDIBSection`

Comment: If you're using _VisualStudio_ as an IDE, I remember that an ancient version (was it 2k5 or even older 6.0?) contained a sample project called DIBLook that was an excellent starting point for handling BMPs (it also contained some MFC stuff that's irrelevant in this context).